# How to drag and drop canvas web element with selenium in chrome

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Need some help on moving a picture inside canvas web element (avatar editor) in chrome using selenium.

Here is a link to canvas element: https://react-avatar-editor.netlify.com

And here is a small demo of what I need to do using Selenium Webdriver: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9pf5eeaktpgu0m7/Screen%20Recording%202019-05-03%20at%2011.48.31%20PM.mov?dl=0

Please see the code sample below.

The same code is working in Firefox, but does not work in Chrome.
Does anybody have an idea where the problem is and how can I solve it?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "pathToChromedriver");
        WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
        wd.manage().window().maximize();
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wd.get("https://react-avatar-editor.netlify.com/");
        WebElement canvas = wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("canvas.editor-canvas"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(wd);
        Action dragAndDrop = builder
                .moveToElement(canvas, 10, 10)
                .pause(2000)
                .clickAndHold()
                .pause(2000)
                .moveToElement(canvas, 100, 100)
                .pause(2000)
                .release()
                .build();
        dragAndDrop.perform();
        wd.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you getting any error message when execute this in chrome?

Comment: Nope, there are no errors

Answer (score 1):

Two changes - one, provide webelement to clickAndHold() and release() methods.
two, the destination coordinates is changed to 10, 100

Action dragAndDrop = 
         builder.moveToElement(canvas, 10, 10)
                .pause(2000)
                .clickAndHold(canvas)
                .pause(2000)
                .moveToElement(canvas, 10, 100)
                .pause(2000)
                .release(canvas)
                .build();
        dragAndDrop.perform();

Comment: builder.moveToElement(canvas, 10, 10)
         .clickAndHold(canvas)
         .moveByOffset(10, 30)
         .release(canvas)
         .build()
         .perform();

Comment: Thanks! Adding element to clickAndHold() and release() method solved the problem fro chrome. In this case I can remove moveToElement() method from chain. So the final working in chrome code would be: builder.clickAndHold(canvas).moveByOffset(100, 100).release(canvas).build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

added pause at the end and the canvas moved to right , with the message "INFO: When using the W3C Action commands, offsets are from the center of element"

```
  .release(canvas)
  .pause(3000)
  .build();
```